# SQL - Grouping COUNT Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query I'm trying to answer is 'How many sales above or equal to 60 has each person made?'

My table (sales$):

```
SaleID  name    salevalue
1   Steve   100
2   John    50
3   Ellen   25
4   Steve   100
5   Mary    60
6   Mary    80
7   John    70
8   Mary    55
9   Steve   65
10  Ellen   120
11  Ellen   30
12  Ellen   40
13  John    40
14  Mary    60
15  Steve   50
```

My code is:

```
select name,
COUNT(*) as 'sales above 60'
from Sales$
group by salevalue, name
having salevalue >= 60;
```

Which gives:

```
Ellen   1
John    1
Mary    2
Mary    1
Steve   1
Steve   2
```

The information is correct in that Mary & Steve both have 3 sales, however I'm forced by the HAVING command to group them out.

Any ideas? I'm sure I've just taken a wrong turning.

Comment: Remove `salevalue` from your GROUP BY.

Comment: Removing `salevalue` from GROUP BY gives an error `Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'Sales$.salevalue' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

The salevalue has to be included to appease the `HAVING` statement.

Comment: Yes, but what are you trying to achieve with that HAVING clause?

Comment: I went down the wrong route with `HAVING`. Swapped it out for a `WHERE` clause and it's now working. (Answer added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this:

```
select name,
       COUNT(case when salevalue >= 60 then 1 end) as 'sales above 60'
from Sales$
group by name
```

This way `COUNT` will take into consideration *only* records having `salevalue >= 60`.

Answer (score 0):

I've swapped the `HAVING` statement for a `WHERE` and achieved the desired result:

`select name, count(*) 'sales above 50'
from sales$
where salevalue >=60
group by name`

(Lightbulb moment after posting)

Comment: Be careful. If some person don't has sales above or equal 60, that person will not be included in result set. But @PJC83 asks 'How many sales above or equal to 60 has EACH PERSON made?'

Comment: Yes, good point, mine didn't account for Zeroes, and the code by Giorgos Bestos did. Thanks.